# Trying to find a work around for giving an element multiple Ids

Tags: javascript, html

So to sum it up I have multiple auto generated anchor tags that send the user to essentially the same place. Since one element cant have 2 ids I create empty spans for each href before my element. How can I get rid of these spans and essentially have an attribute in my table be equal to multiple ids. Also due to the structure the href on  tags cant be the same.

```
<a href ="#autoGeneratedHref1"></a>
<a href ="#autoGeneratedHref2"</a>
<span id ="autoGeneratedHref1"></span><span id ="autoGeneratedHref2"></span>
<table>This is the table users want to be linked to by both hrefs</table>
```

Comment: How do you autogenerate these tags? May be you should generate links with the same id?

Comment: Why not use Class !!??

Comment: Given the situation (anchors are auto generated and assuming that you could not change this) it seems a good solution for me.

Comment: Tried with the classes initally but due to a complicated situation that wont be working

Comment: How complicated is the situation? We might be able to help.

Comment: Resolved, ended up using custom data attributes